# How To start multiple mySQL instances on boot

Tags: mysql, linux

I currently have 3 mySQL instances on my Linux Centos 64 bit server.  When the server boots up it only starts the first mySQL instance.  At that point I have to "mysqld_multi stop" then "mysqld_multi start" to ensure all 3 are started.  Is there anyway Linux can start all 3 up at run time so I don't have to do this every time I reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use crontab @reboot option:
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Answer (score 0):

After researching this a little bit, it looks like you don't have too many options and they aren't as elegant as I would like.

### Creating a separate mysql server instance

[Running Multiple MySQL 5.6 Instances on one server in CentOS 6/RHEL 6/Fedora](http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/running-multiple-mysql-5-6-instances-on-one-server-in-centos-6rhel-6fedora/)

This link explains pretty well how to create another MySQL server instance that starts at boot time. You could definitely do things better than he describes, but this is a start. Essentially he copies the `/etc/init.d/mysqld` startup script and the `/etc/my.cnf` configuration file and has the new startup script reference the new configuration file.

### Creating a unified startup script

You could also `chkconfig mysqld off` to not use mysql's built-in startup script and create your own that runs your `mysqld_multi` commands at boot time.

Let me know if you are looking for more information.

Comment: Have you a complete script?

Comment: What OS do you need a script for? In CentOS 6, the MySQL-server RPM provides a very simple script (`/usr/share/mysql/mysqld_multi.server`). However, this script doesn't wait for the databases to be ready to respond to queries. The script only starts the databases and immediately exits.

Comment: I'm using Debian - and I've wrote now my own script.

Comment: http://it-raboese.de/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=mysql:administration&#datenbank_start_stop
Hmpf.. can't edit last comment.